Finance: investment analysis

What is the correlation coefficient if beta of stock is 1.714, standard deviation stock is 12% and standard deviation market is 20%?

I was tackling this problem and i used the correlation coefficient formula which is: "(standard deviation Market * beta Stock)/standard deviation Stock" and i get a correlation  coefficient bigger than 1 which is impossible.
What am i doing wrong?

Good question: it looks like one of those numbers given to you must be wrong.  Because many readers of this post might not be familiar with investing jargon, it might help to explain that the "beta" is just the slope in a regression of the stock's returns against the market's returns.

The correct formula for the correlation coefficient is:
$$
\text{Correlation Coefficient} = \frac{\text{Beta of Stock} \times \text{Standard Deviation of Stock}}{\text{Standard Deviation of Market}}
$$
Using the given values:
$$\begin{align}
\text{Correlation Coefficient}& = \frac{1.714 \times 0.12}{0.20}\\&=\frac{0.20568}{0.20}\\&= 1.028\end{align}.
$$
The incorrect formula you used is:
$$
\text{Correlation Coefficient} = \frac{\text{Standard Deviation of Market} \times \text{Beta of Stock}}{\text{Standard Deviation of Stock}}
$$
Using the given values in this incorrect formula:
$$\begin{align}
\text{Correlation Coefficient} &= \frac{0.20 \times 1.714}{0.12}\\& = \frac{0.3428}{0.12} \\&= 2.857\end{align}.
$$
This result is incorrect because the correlation coefficient cannot exceed $ 1$.

hey thank for your explanation but isn't beta Stock = (correlation coefficient  * standard deviation stock) / standard deviation Market ?

It is a mathematical fact that a correlation coefficient cannot be larger than $1$ in magnitude. (-1)
